# matching fields in a database, ASP.net (VB)

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, field

In a table I have news posts with these fields:

- Title
- Content
- OwnerID

And a users table

- ID
- Name
- Surname

The OwnerID relates to the ID in the users table, how can I get the name of the user who's  ID matches the OwnerID?

I'm writing a website in ASP.net (VB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to join the two tables together like this:

```
select users.Name
from news inner join users
    on OwnerID = ID;
```

This query has no `where` clause to filter the results that are returned so this query would return all users who are associated with a `news` record.  If you wanted to find users associated with a specific news record you would need to filter on the news title or content like this:

```
select users.Name
from news inner join users
    on OwnerID = ID
where Title = 'Some Title';
```